# Uncaught ReferenceError: wins is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a code for a rock paper scissors game and even though I defined all the variables I need, none of them are getting defined according to the console. I declared all of my 3 variables, wins, ties and losses in an object, and they aren't registering. This is my object:

```
      const score={
        wins:0,
        losses:0,
        ties:0
      };
```

This is the if statement where the error is occurring:

```
if(result==='You win!'){
        score.wins=wins++;
      } else if(result==='Tie.'){
        score.ties=ties++;
      } else if(result==='You lose.'){
        score.losses=losses++;
      }
```

And the is the alert that i'm trying to pass through:

```
      alert(`You picked ${playerMove}. Computer picked ${computerMove}. ${result}.\n  Wins: ${score.wins}. \n  Ties: ${score.ties}. \n  Losses: ${score.losses}.`);
```

Can someone please help me with this.

credits to SuperSimpleDev for the tutorial and the course.

```
      const score={
        wins:0,
        losses:0,
        ties:0
      };
```

This is the if statement where the error is occurring:

```
if(result==='You win!'){
        score.wins=wins++;
      } else if(result==='Tie.'){
        score.ties=ties++;
      } else if(result==='You lose.'){
        score.losses=losses++;
      }
```

And the is the alert that i'm trying to pass through:

```
      alert(`You picked ${playerMove}. Computer picked ${computerMove}. ${result}.\n  Wins: ${score.wins}. \n  Ties: ${score.ties}. \n  Losses: ${score.losses}.`);
```

Can someone please help me with this.

credits to SuperSimpleDev for the tutorial and the course.

Comment: Instead of `score.wins=wins++` you want `score.wins++` etc.  You have not defined `wins` (or `ties` or `losses`) anywhere in the code you have in your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change it to `score.wins++` or `score.wins = score.wins + 1`

Currently you're trying to `++` 'wins' which isn't its own thing.  It's part of the 'score' object, so referring to 'wins' by itself will return undefined.